# Batch script factorial recursive

Tags: batch-file

```
    @echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
:: Fiche 3 Exercice 6
Title Fiche 3 Exercice 6
color B4
Mode con cols=100 lines=40

echo CALCULATRICE FACTORIELLE
set /p nbToCalc=Entre le nombre : 
set /a fact=1
call :CalcFact %nbToCalc%

:finfact
echo.
pause
exit

:CalcFact
if !nbToCalc! gtr 0 (
    set /a fact= !nbToCalc! * %fact%(!nbToCalc! - 1)
    goto :CalcFact
) else (
    goto :finfact
)
```

State 1 :
Write a script that calculates and displays the factorial of a number.
The script will call aa recursive function.
The number is passed as a parameter when the script is launched.
The function will return the factorial of the number passed in parameter.
See the following link: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorielle

Remark:
When, in a block of repeating instructions, you access a variable
surround its name with '! and not '%'. Add this at the beginning of the program:
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion1

Comment: What you say "Write a script", are you sure it must be a batchfile? Why not Powershell? Or any UNIX script?

Comment: I can't see any question about your homework?

Comment: As with your last question the task is completely pointless. The reason I say that is because `Set /A` is only capable of working with 32 bit integers. That means that the integer passed to your label via the `Call` command, cannot be larger than `12`. The factorial of `13` would be `6227020800`, which is greater than the maximum `2147483647`. There is no reason therefore not to use a simple `If` command structure, essentially a table `if %~1 equ 12 exit /b 479001600`, then you can `echo %errorlevel%`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't recursive - it's just calling a loop. Recursive means a called function *calls* itself (instead of jumping to its beginning):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set fact=1
set /p num=Enter number:

call :fact %num%
echo %errorlevel%
goto :eof

:fact
set /a fact*=num , num-=1
if %num% gtr 0 call :fact
exit /b %fact%
```

Keep in mind that it only works with numbers less than 13 (1..12) because of the 32bit limitation of `set /p`. Bigger numbers give false results. Maybe you want to check the userinput for a valid range.

*(Just a word of advice: your teacher surely knows how to google, so just dumping all of your assignments here might not be the wisest idea ever.)*

Attention: `call` remembers its "return address" on a stack. This stack is limited and exceeding the stack results in a severe (script-breaking) error. (Not a problem in this case, because factorials escalate quickly and hit the 32-bit limitation first)

Comment: Thanks you Stephan that wasn't an assignements just somes exercices we need to learn to pass an exam.. Don't worry about that